# How to reuse an already calculated column in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to reuse an already calculated `SELECT` column?

Current query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Mod),
    SUM(Mod) - SUM(Spent)
FROM 
    tblHelp 
GROUP BY 
    SourceID
```

Pseudo query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Mod),
    USE ALREADY CALCULATED VALUE - SUM(Spent)
FROM 
    tblHelp 
GROUP BY 
    SourceID
```

Question: since `SUM(Mod)` is already calculated, can I put it in temp variable and use it in other columns in the `SELECT` clause? Will doing so increase the efficiency of SQL query?

Comment: No, there's no point to this. The optimizer is not so silly that it will actually scan the table multiple times. Only a single scan will be used for all `SUM`s at once. (The `SUM` then may or may not be done twice, but that isn't a bottleneck on a per-row basis, and any rewrites you do won't speed things up -- in fact they are more than likely to slow things down instead.)

Comment: The query optimiser will *reuse* the expression multiple times, you can easily validate that by reviewing the *compute scalar* operators in the execution plan.

Answer (score 3):

A subquery could do this for you, but it won't make any difference to sql server. If you think that this would make the query more readable than go ahead, here is an example

```
select t.modsum,
       t.modsum - t.modspent
from   ( SELECT SUM(Mod) as modsum,
                SUM(Spent) as modspent
         FROM tblHelp 
         GROUP BY SourceID
       ) t
```

But, is this more readable for you than

```
SELECT SUM(Mod),
       SUM(Mod) - SUM(Spent)
FROM   tblHelp 
GROUP BY SourceID
```

IMHO I don't find the first query more readable. That could change off course when the query gets much bigger and more complicated.

There won't be any improvement to performance, so the only reason to do this is to make it more clear/readable for you

Comment: Can you explain why it would not make any improvement to performance?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least not directly.
You can use tricks such as using a derived table or a cte or `cross apply` but you can't use a value computed in the `select` clause in the same `select` clause.

example:

```sql
SELECT SumMode, SumMode - SumSpent
FROM
(
SELECT 
      SUM(Mod) As SumMode,
      SUM(Spent) As SumSpent
      FROM tblHelp GROUP BY SourceID
) As DerivedTable;
```

It will probably not increase performance, but for complicated computation it can help with code clarity, though.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a quite intelligent query parser, so while I can't prove it I would be very surprised if it didn't calculate it only once. However, you can make sure of it with:

```
select x.SourceId, x.Mod, x.Mod - x.Spent
from 
(
    select SourceId, sum(Mod) Mod, sum(Spent) Spent
    from tblHelp
    group by SourceId
) x
```

)

Comment: If you want to get technical, that rewrite will not, in fact "make sure of it", because the optimizer is *not* beholden to respecting subqueries (or CTEs) in terms of evaluation order. It will merrily interpolate the query, and if it did come up with an execution plan where the sum is done more than once, that would be applied here too (although it's not probable that it would do so in the first place, of course).

Comment: @JeroenMostert - yeah. If I'd seen your and @ Stu's comments I wouldn't have answered.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already cover some good ground, but please note:

1. Surely you should not `select` into a `@variable` to "save" one sum and then make a new `select` on your table alongside with that value, because you will be scanning the table *twice*.
2. I understand how one would try to optimize performance by thinking low-level (CPU operations), which would lead you to think of avoiding extra summations. However, SQL Server is a different beast. You have to learn to read the execution plan, and the data pages involved. If your code avoids uneccessary page reads, doing more cpu work (if even that happens) is very usually negligible. In layman's terms for your case: if the table has few rows, it probably isn't worth even thinking. If it has many, reading the entirety of those pages from disk (and sorting them due to the `group`ing `by` iff no index exists) will take 99.99% of time relative to adding the values for the sums